# ACF field not displaying on index.php generated pages in Twenty Seventeen theme

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to generate a custom image above the user generated content that is NOT the header image. I'm dong this with ACF. The expected result displays on pages generated by page.php, but NOT on index.php which the client site is using as a posts page.

Tried placing the code everywhere conceivable. Wordpress debug and just writing the word TEST indicates that my positioning and files are not incorrect.

```
<div class="wrap">
<?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>

    <header class="page-header">
<img src="<?php the_field('image-head'); ?>" style="display: block; margin: auto; margin-bottom: 10px;"/> //Relevant ACF code which displays on pages generated by the page.php file without issue

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>
<?php else : ?>

<header class="page-header">
    <h2 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Posts', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></h2>
</header>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_pagination(
                array(
                    'prev_text'          => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
                    'next_text'          => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ),
                    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . ' </span>',
                )
            );

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: <img src="<?php the_field('image-head'); ?>" style="display: block; margin: auto; margin-bottom: 10px;"/>

ACF code. Don't know why it cut off.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/value-loading-posts-page/. I'm assuming you've set it up to return the URL of the image.

```php
<?php 
$imageUrl = get_field('image-head', get_option('page_for_posts'));

if( !empty($imageUrl) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl;?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

The Query on the index page is the blog posts not the page so you have to specifically tell ACF that you want the field from the page (same goes for other archive pages).